# Getting latest entry from multiple groups in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Apologies if the question title is not clear. Don't really know how to phrase the following in one line.

I hope I mange to explain what I want to achieve. This is wrecking me head.

Currently I have a table which keeps a record for the training status of employees for different projects. Structure is like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|id|timestamp           |employee  |project    |status       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |2015-10-01 00:00:00 | john doe | project_1 | In Training |
|2 |2015-10-04 00:00:00 | jane doe | project_1 | In Training |
|3 |2015-11-01 00:00:00 | john doe | project_1 | Live        |
|4 |2015-10-08 00:00:00 | john doe | project_2 | In Training |
|5 |2015-11-01 00:00:00 | jane doe | project_2 | In Training |
|6 |2015-11-09 00:00:00 | jane doe | project_3 | Live        |
```

Now management requested a table / view which gives an overview about the  latest status per employee. So I'm looking for a query which returns this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| employee | project_1   | project_2   | project_3   |
-----------------------------------------------------
| John Doe | Live        | In Training |             |
| Jane Doe | In Training | In Training | Live        |
```

So the query should look for the latest entry per employee and project and return the status of that project.

Is there any way this is doable?

Comment: And you want it pivoted in columns? :-(

Comment: Yes - that is the big problem with this one. Right now I manages to find the last timestamp. with "SELECT user_id, max(if(project='project_1',timestamp,' ')) as '#1', max(if(project='project_2',timestamp,' ')) as '#2', max(if(project='project_3',timestamp,' ')) as '#3'
FROM a_training_status
GROUP BY user_id" - How would I be able to get the status which maches these timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're conflating 2 problems into 1. The first problem is how to get the latest status per employee per project. The second is how to show the data in columns. The first problem is more interesting, so that's the one I'll answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.employee
              , y.project
              , z.timestamp
              , z.status 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
           LEFT 
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT a.* 
                  FROM my_table a 
                  JOIN 
                     ( SELECT employee 
                            , project
                            , MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp 
                         FROM my_table 
                        GROUP 
                           BY employee
                            , project
                     ) b 
                    ON b.employee = a.employee 
                   AND b.project = a.project 
                   AND b.max_timestamp = a.timestamp
              ) z 
             ON z.employee = x.employee 
            AND z.project = y.project;
```